# vim: Why SHIFT+H and SHIFT+L not jumping on the first and last line on the screen?

Tags: vim

I'm using vim included in Fedora 29:

VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Feb  4 2019 14:19:12)

and I just noticed that by pressing H or L the cursor is not jumping on the first and last line on the screen. Something has been changed in the software? Because I think it was working back in time...

EDIT: also when scrolling with CTRL-E and CTRL-Y there's 5 lines at top and 5 lines at bottom as a "margin"

Comment: Added some mappings? Let's check: `:map! H` and `:map! L`

Comment: No mapping found

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something has set the `scrolloff` option to a non-default value.  Run `:verbose set scrolloff` to see where it's being set.

Comment: scrolloff=5 What is the default value?

Comment: okay, I managed to set to 0 in vim. But when I exit and start vim again the value is 5 again. I changed /etc/vimrc but has no effect

Comment: okay, I found it... it is in "/usr/share/vim/vim81/defaults.vim" -- I changed from 5 to 0 the scrolloff. Now it's fine. But why was this changed?

Comment: That is a question for whoever packages vim for your Linux distribution. Rather than changing it in that file you should just override it in your own `.vimrc`.